# How to create an object in dynamoDB using lambda?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

so i have this simple lambda function that simply creates a user object in my personal user table. When i click on test, it returns null. But i am not sure what the error is?

Here is my lambda function:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamoDBConfiguration = 
{
    "accessKeyId": "###", 
    "secretAccessKey": "###",
    "region": "MY_REGION"
};
AWS.config.update(dynamoDBConfiguration);
//var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB(); 
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); 
exports.handler = function(event, context) 
{
    console.log('stageA');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, '  '));
    var responseCode = 200;
    var userTableName = "usersTable";
    var requestBody = event.body;
    var pathParams = event.path;
    var httpMethod = event.httpMethod;  // HTTP Method (e.g., POST, GET, HEAD)
    //User parameters
    var displayName;
    var email;
    var fbUserID;
    var firstName;
    var folders;
    var lastName;
    var origin;
    var profileImageRef;
    var level;
    var username;
    var birthdate;
    var experience;
    var folder;
    var params;

     console.log('create by email action');
        requestBody = JSON.parse(requestBody);
         //Set variables
        firstName = requestBody.firstName;
        lastName = requestBody.lastName;
        email = requestBody.email;
        username = requestBody.username;
        experience = "0";
        birthdate = requestBody.birthdate;

        params = {
            TableName:userTableName,
            Item:{
                "displayName": username,
                "email": email,
                "firstName": firstName,
                "folderNames": {
                    "My Cards": {"name": "My Cards"}
                },
                "lastName": lastName,
                "experience": experience,
                "username": username,
                "birthdate": birthdate
            }
        };
        dynamodb.put(params, function(err, data) 
            { if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    context.done(err);
                } else {
                    var response = 
                    {
                        statusCode: responseCode,
                        headers: 
                        {
                            "x-custom-header" : "custom header value"
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(username)
                    };
                    console.log('great success: %j',data);
                    context.succeed(response);
                }
            });


};
```

And in my request body i have:

```
{
  "email":"tomSample@gmail.com",
  "birthdate" : "1/1/1990",
  "firstName" : "Tom",
  "lastName" : "Sir",
  "username" : "Archer"
}
```

Comment: Just a side comment -- there should be no need to put credentials in a Lambda function. Simply assign a Role to the function and it inherits the permissions automatically.

Comment: Add some logging. Add some try/catch blocks. Include the log output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code invoking through API Gateway endpoint and it worked fine. In your post when you meant invoking "test" is it the test option inside the Lambda console? If that is the case, make sure that you have selected "API Gateway AWS Proxy" as the Sample event template.

After you have selected "API Gateway AWS Proxy" event template to test, edit the body in the payload and add your request body to it. Make sure to escape the double quotes.

The other way to test your Lambda is to invoke your API Gateway endpoint. Make sure your API Gateway is deployed after any changes you have made before invoking the API. I used Postman and was successfully able to POST the request you mentioned to DynamoDB table